# Assistance setting up a double integral bounded by the upper nappe of $z^2=x^2+y^2$ and above the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=9$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, volume

So basically I need to find the volume of a solid bounded below by the upper nappe of the cone $z^2=x^2+y^2$ and bounded above by the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=9$

I know it looks like this:

[image: The region]

But I'm not sure how to setup the double integral to find the volume.  I do understand what my limits of integration will be and that I will need to do some conversions to polar coordinates, but I don't understand how to find the functions to integrate.

Any hints or tips are greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

After thinking about the problem a little more, is it a matter of just adding the two functions together?

For example:

$$\iint \sqrt{x^2+y^2}+\sqrt{9-x^2-y^2}\;dy\;dx$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both surfaces intersect at $z=3/\sqrt{2},$ and the projection of this intersection in the $xy$ plane in a circle $C$ centered at $(0,0)$ with radius $r=3/\sqrt{2}$. Let $D$ be the disc with border $C$.

It follows that

$$V=\iint_D \sqrt{9-x^2-y^2}-\sqrt{x^2+y^2} dA,$$

which should be easy to integrate with polar coordinates given the nature of the function to integrate, and the nature of $D$.

Alternatively, spherical coordinates should work too here. Your solid can be written as

$$
E=\{(\rho,\theta,\phi)\;|\; 0\le \rho\le 3, 0\le \theta\le 2\pi, 0\le \phi \le \pi/4 \}
$$
You can most surely take it from there.

Comment: Having trouble understanding how you got that point of intersection?

Comment: Plug $z^2=x^2+y^2$ in $x^2+y^2+z^2=9$ to get $2z^2=9$.

Comment: OK, so I came up with the following: $\int^{2\pi}_{0}\int^{\frac{3\sqrt{2}}{2}}_{0}\sqrt{9-r^2}-r\;r\;dr\;d\theta$?

Comment: That looks good. Make sure the $r$ in $rdrd\theta$ applies for $\sqrt{9-r^2}$ and $r$ (in other words put parentheses).

Comment: Got it!  Thanks for your help.  It now looks like this:  $\int^{2\pi}_{0}\int^{\frac{3\sqrt{2}}{2}}_{0}r \sqrt{9-r^2}-r^2\;dr\;d\theta$

Comment: Updated my comment

Comment: The answer I get after evaluating the integral is negative, which it shouldn't be for the volume?  $-9(\sqrt{2}-2)\pi$

Comment: Indeed a volume should always be positive. But look carefully, your answer IS positive. And it is correct.